# Samsung TV Tizen resources not loading over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, samsung-smart-tv, tizen, tizen-emulator, tizen-web-simulator

I've been building a Samsung TV app that plays several YouTube video's through the VideoJS player. Note: The app is only tested in an emulator and not on a Samsung Tizen TV. Whenever a resource is loaded over HTTPS, I get the following console message:

> Failed to load resource: Loading page cancelled because of untrusted connection. https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9fFv244_X88/hqdefault.jpg

Or as the image shows here:

[image: Tizen Console log]

As it seems, resources loaded over HTTPS get marked untrusted. I have a **valid security profile**, both the Author Certificate and the Distributor Certificate. When manually changing the image urls to http only, it does work. But the video is not loaded, since YouTube automatically redirects it to the HTTPS envi, hence the issue remains.

On a sidenote, I've given access to any external source by using a wildcard in the access policy: 
`<access origin="*" subdomains="true"></access>`

When catching up with the VideoJS error log, it says the video is encrypted but no keys are present to decrypt. Pretty sure this is an SSL issue.

Limited, free beer provided to my savior.

Comment: Does your connection allow HTTPS requests? What happens if you open the app on a desktop browser?

Comment: Yes, it does. When running it in a desktop browser, there are no issues related to SSL.

Comment: Are you using any custom root certificate(s) on your desktop?

Comment: Nope, starting to think this is a Tizen related issue.

Comment: I have tried on the real device and it works...so i guess may be emulator issue.

Comment: Exactly, tested it out too and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is the certificate IP bound or is it a TLS Certificate with SNI extension? I am not sure if Tizen supports [SNI TLS extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

Answer (score 0):

This has come to bite me in 2019 when building a Tizen wearable app that supports the Samsung Gear S2 watch which was rejecting ajax requests to my free shared CloudFlare SSL certificate. Using a dedicate certificate which only lists your domain fixes the issue. All newer watches (Gear S3, Galaxy Watch, Galaxy Watch Active) running Tizen seem to support the shared certificate without issue. Seems to be an issue with the Tizen version 2.3.2.